# Parallel iteration over XML nodes with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML of this kind:

```
<xml>
    <node1>1.1</node1>
    <node1>1.2</node1>
    <node1>1.3</node1>

    <node2>2.1</node2>
    <node2>2.2</node2>
    <node2>2.3</node2>

    <node3>3.1</node3>
    <node3>3.2</node3>
    <node3>3.3</node3>
</xml>
```

and I want to get the following output:
line: 1.1 + 2.1 + 3.1
line: 1.2 + 2.2 + 3.2
line: 1.3 + 2.3 + 3.3

Is there a way I can iterate over these nodes simultaneously and keep track of my current position in each of three lists or do I have to wrap these items into a bigger block and iterate over blocks?

I'm using XSL 1.0.

Comment: Should that third block of elements be of type `<node3>` instead of `<node2>`?

Comment: @ABach You're right. Blind copy-paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As easy as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node1">
   <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
     <xsl:value-of select=". + ../node2[$vPos] + ../node3[$vPos]"/>
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document (based on the provided one):**

```
<xml>
    <node1>1</node1>
    <node1>2</node1>
    <node1>3</node1>

    <node2>4</node2>
    <node2>5</node2>
    <node2>6</node2>

    <node3>7</node3>
    <node3>8</node3>
    <node3>9</node3>
</xml>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
12
15
18
```

**Do note**:

1. In XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 one can use the **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)** template/function **[`zip-with3()`](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-zipWith3.xsl?revision=1.1&view=markup)**.
2. In XPath 3.0 (XSLT 3.0) there will be a standard function [**`map-pairs()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-map-pairs), but there is no `map-tripples()` standard function. One can use this function to produce an intermediate result and then use it again to produce the final result.
3. As noted by Ian Roberts, the presence of `xsl:strip-space` in this solution is important -- without it the `position()` function produces different results and the transformation doesn't perform as required.

Comment: Note that the `strip-space` is vital to make this work, without that the `position()`s won't line up because the current node list in the `node1` template will include the (whitespace) text nodes between the `node1` elements.  To be more robust, add a `<xsl:template match="xml"><xsl:apply-templates select="node1" /></xsl:template>` to make the current node list contain just the three `node1` elements and nothing else.

Comment: I didn't mean to criticise, I just wanted to highlight this as a learning point - in my experience your answers to XSLT questions are always right but sometimes rather magical to anyone who is not as intimately familiar with XSLT as yourself ;-)

Comment: @IanRoberts, Yes, your observation is right -- I wish I had always the time to go into detailed explanations...

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, You've already helped me out a couple of times and now another great answer. Just adapted it a bit to get what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a builtin way in XSLT to do that. I guess you could implement it yourself easily by applying the [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) technique.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand how I can use that. Do you mean I should first map the lists like `<node1/> -> <node1><value/><id/><node1>` and then use those IDs to match list positions?

Comment: This has nothing to do with MapReduce, parallel execution, etc. He just wants to visit node values in an order other than the document order.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following does the job (independent of the number and names of child elements of the `xml` element):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name="name" match="xml/*" use="local-name()"/>

<xsl:variable name="first" select="xml/*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('name', local-name())[1])]"/>

<xsl:template match="xml">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$first[1]" mode="init"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xml/*" mode="init">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('name', local-name())" mode="line"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xml/*" mode="line">
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:text>line: </xsl:text>
  <xsl:for-each select="$first">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:text> + </xsl:text></xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('name', local-name())[$pos]"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xml/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Martin, Seems that you take the question too-literally. I believe that the OP wants to have the sum of the identically-positioned elements -- each on a separate line. Also, such generalization goes too-far -- the real XML document may contain other siblings, which shouldn't participate in the sum.

Comment: I see your answer was accepted some minutes ago but it was not clear to me that the sum of three different but known child elements should simply be computed, I assumed that the contents of elements should be output.

Comment: Yes, now it is evident that the OP wanted the sum computed.