# How to generate vertical tables in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml as below which i need to translate using xslt.

```
<table-text>
    <widget-wrap> <firstname lang="en">first name 1</firstname></widget-wrap>
    <widget-wrap><lastname>last name 1</lastname></widget-wrap>
    <widget-wrap><email>email 1</email></widget-wrap>
</table-text>

<table-text>
<widget-wrap><firstname lang="en">first name 2</firstname></widget-wrap>
<widget-wrap><lastname>last name 2</lastname></widget-wrap>
<widget-wrap><email>email 2</email></widget-wrap>
</table-text>

<table-text>
<widget-wrap><firstname lang="en">first name 3</firstname></widget-wrap>
<widget-wrap><lastname>last name 3</lastname></widget-wrap>
<widget-wrap><email>email 3</email></widget-wrap>
</table-text>
```

The output shoule be a vertical table as below:

```
 <table>
      <tr>
   <td>first name 1</td>
   <td>first name 2</td>
   <td>first name 3</td>
   </tr>
<tr>
    <td>last name 1</td>
    <td>last name 2</td>
    <td>last name 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>email 1</td>
    <td>email 2</td>
    <td>email 3</td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

Can someone please help me to get this sorted out. Thanks heaps.

Comment: You need to know the basics of XSLT -- this is a very easy and straight-forward problem to solve with XSLT. On the other side, if you don't know such basic things, you will not be able to understand any answer, therefore you will have no benefit from other people doing your homework. -1.

Comment: Mate, this aint a homework. I am using Apache Cocoon to do a legacy web app for a client and thought i post this question. It is just that i am meeting deadlines for this project thus the above...I am more of a frontend developer and this is first time am having a real play with xslt.

Comment: This SO question and answer look very similar to what you're trying to accomplish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379853/parallel-iteration-over-xml-nodes-with-xslt

Answer (score 1):

One issue with your input is that valid XML can only have one root node, so you'll need to wrap all of the table-text elements in another element before executing your XSLT.

As long as there are no missing firstname, lastname, or email elements, this is very simple:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//firstname"/>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//lastname"/>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//email"/>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="firstname">
        <td><xsl:apply-templates /></td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="lastname">
        <td><xsl:apply-templates /></td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="email">
        <td><xsl:apply-templates /></td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If some of the elements may be missing, then this becomes quite a bit more difficult. Hopefully this is all you need.